# Pthread_create causing segmentation fault (C++, Kubutnu 15)

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I am in shock and confusion, be honestly. After reading several dozen topics on "pthread_create causing segmentation fault" I still have this problem. I did everything that was ordered, and the result is zero: at the stage of debug, program gives segmentation fault on the line creation process.

I already do not understand anything. I would be grateful for your help. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <interfacemanager.h>
using namespace std;

InterfaceManager IFACE;



void* watch_for_interfaces(void*)
{
    IFACE.monitoring();
}



int main()
{

        sigset_t   *set;
        sigemptyset(&(*set));
        sigaddset(&(*set), SIGINT);
        sigaddset(&(*set), SIGTERM);

        pthread_t th1, th2;
        int i=1;
        if (pthread_create(&th2, NULL, watch_for_interfaces, (void*)&i) != 0) {
          perror("th2 error\n");
          exit(1);
        }




        printf ("Terminating\nPress eny key\n");
        getchar();

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: things to fix:  1) do not mix C++ with C header files.  if compiled with gcc, the C++ header file function definitions will not be usable because the compiler will not have 'mangled' the function names.  If compiled with g++, the C header file function definitions will not be usable because the compiler will have 'mangled' the function names.

Comment: more things to fix: 2) the line: 'exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);' will exit the program, so the 'return 0;' statement will be unreachable code.  3) if compiled with gcc, the #include <iostream> will fail to find the file.  4) in function 'watch_for_interfaces()' a) suggest using 'camel case' rather than underscores for word separation b) exit a thread with a call to 'pthread_exit()', not by falling off the end of the function

Comment: more things to fix: 5) main() should call 'pthread_join( th2 );' to gracefully wait for the thread to exit, before exiting from main().   6) strongly suggest compiling with gcc AND removing the #include <iostream> statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `pthread_create` but with your signal functions.

```
    sigset_t   *set;
    sigemptyset(&(*set));
    sigaddset(&(*set), SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&(*set), SIGTERM);
```

Here, you are using an uninitialized variable `set` and passing it to signal functions which is *undefined*. You could `malloc` it but it's necessary you can write it as

```
    sigset_t   set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGTERM);
```

Comment: Yeah, about the same decision and came at me. The problem is greater in the noodles code than semantics.

Thank you very much!